# php for loop does not update each iteration in to MySql DB Table

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, sql-update

Hi I am trying to update a database table rows with the same row ID using PHP for loop but it only updates all the rows in the database table with the last iteration data when i ECHO the update query it shows the correct update code in each iteration  below i have included the code and necessary screenshots

PHP ForLoop code

```
 if (!empty($_POST['cycleStartDate']) && !empty($_POST['mainSystemLink'])  && !empty($_POST['paymentMethod'])) {

        $invoice_stat = 'no';

// Assuming you have the initial payment date


// If payment method is monthly, add 1 month to the current date for the next iteration
        if ($paymentMethod == 'monthly') {
            $description = $_POST['mainSystemLink']; // Assuming the description is the same for all iterations
            $amount = $_POST['payment']; // Assuming the amount is the same for all iterations
            $aId = $_POST['AutoId']; // Assuming the AutoId is the same for all iterations
            $cycleStartDate = $_POST['cycleStartDate'];

            for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
                // Construct the query
                $query = "UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '$cycleStartDate', `description`='$main_sys_link', `amount`='$payment', `payment_method`='$paymentMethod'  WHERE `project_id`='$proj_id'";
                // Execute the query
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                // Update paymentDate for the next iteration
                $cycleStartDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cycleStartDate . ' +1 month'));

                echo $query;
            }
        }
```

update query echo output

```
59Record updated successfullyUPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-01-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-02-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-03-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-04-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-05-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-06-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-07-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-08-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-09-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-10-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-11-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'UPDATE `hosting_payment` SET `payment_date` = '2024-12-05', `description`='www.dasisprinters.com1' , `amount`='30000', `payment_method`='monthly' WHERE `project_id`='59'
```

Database Screenshots

[image]

please can you guys check and let me know the necessary fixes

THANKS FOR YOUR VALUABLE TIME

Comment: You always use project_id to identify the rows to update - so it will update all rows with that as the value.  You need to use your first column (host_p....) to identify the specific row.

Answer (score 0):

Before you read this answer, let me remind you that your code is prone to SQL injection and it's highly insecure, users might pass malicious scripts as the values they post which are then executed in your database updates, causing your system harm.

---

The

```
WHERE `project_id`='$proj_id'
```

specifies that all records whose `project_id` equals your `$proj_id` will be updated accordingly. If you need to differentiate them by row number, then you can use a variable, like

```
set @rn = 0;

update yourtable set yourfield = (@rn := @rn + 1)
where `project_id` = 59
```

Comment: Is row number a particularly useful way of knowing which row to update?

Comment: @NigelRen it does not seem to be the case, but since the question wondered about it, I have focused on doing it. If there is a particularly useful way to define which row should be updated to what value, then I will haply edit my answer.

Comment: the payment_date should start from 2024-01-05 and add 1 month to every iteration  which should finish from 2024-12-05 but it updates all the records as 2024-12-05

Comment: but when I eco the query it shows the update correctly i have provided the echo out put above in the question

Comment: @AsyadNazeem the `where` clause is fulfilled by all records involved. So all the updates update all the 59 records. Therefore the second update overrides the first, the third overrides the second and so on.

Comment: @AsyadNazeem happy to help. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer. If you still have some problems to solve, then please let me know so I could help.